# Google Elevation API, Resolution is very poor

Tags: android, json, google-maps-api-3, google-elevation-api

I am writing a jogging tracker app that gets Locations from Google Maps, and sends them to Google Elevation api to get the elevation.

It works fine. My problem is the resolution is very(!) poor.
it is around 152 m.
In my case, I cannot relay on it..
Did anyone encounter this problem and find a way to overcome the problem?
Is there any other reliable services for Elevation data?

Since in the documentation, Google mention that sending array of locations can reduce accuracy, I send single locations, and got the same results...
Here are my results (I crossed out the actual locations)

```
    {
    "results" : [
    {
        "elevation" : 250.5070190429688,
        "location" : {
            "lat" : XXXXXXXX,
            "lng" : XXXXXXXX
        },
        "resolution" : 152.7032318115234 
    },
    {
        "elevation" : 249.131103515625, 
        "location" : {
            "lat" : XXXXXXXXX,
            "lng" : XXXXXXXXX
        },
        "resolution" : 152.7032318115234
    }
    ],
    "status" : "OK"
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think it depends on location. At my position I get 9.5 meters of resolution

Comment: Yes. It probably does depend on location :(

Answer (score 0):

It is funny that for every pair of coordinates I have tried, I get the same resolution = 152.7032318115234, even if for instance, elevation on google earth looks like LIDAR data.

POINT,  LAT,    LON,    ELEV,   RESOLUTION, STATUS
POINT_Rivas,    40.365640,  -3.525575,  696.0855102539062,  152.7032318115234,  OK

Comment: I assume your coordinates are from the same area I sent mine... I was told it is so in some areas for security matters.